# WiFi password doesn't work on Ubuntu 12

Tags: wireless, password

I jusy installed Ubuntu 12.04 and had a lot of problems getting the WiFi to be recognized. But even as I solved that issue I cannot yet get connect with my WiFi, as my (100% sure) correct password is not accepted and the system keep asking me for the password.
Anybody here could help?
Thnks a lot!

Comment: What the logs say? Ring-ding-ding-ding-dingeringeding?

Answer (score -1):

Try installing any Updates to Ubuntu and if that doesn't work try using Ubuntu 13.10. I had the same issues until the system was updated.

An alternate suggestion that you boot into Ubuntu with a different version of Linux, you should be able to do this from booting up the computer and then selecting "Advanced Options for Ubuntu" and selecting another version to boot into.

Comment: Could you explain how that solves OP problem, and how OP could do that?

Comment: Yeah, all you need to do is use the GRUB loader when booting up and then select "Advanced Options for Ubuntu" and then choose the second option down, it should then boot into Ubuntu and it should also make the WiFi work, then once a connection is established perform any and all system updates, and then reboot and boot into Ubuntu as normal and the WiFi should work.

I had the same issue myself and the fix I mentioned work for me.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and say that?